# JQuery Deselect Checkbox once greater than max limit

Tags: html, jquery, checkbox, limit

So we have a group of checkboxes. There is a max limit of 3 that can be selected which is great. This is for a product designer I am working on so I can make custom orders for people. I have noticed when testing that people get frustrated when they want to go and click another checkbox but since the three have been picked they have to go back and uncheck a checkbox before making another selection. Its not the biggest deal but I would like for that flow to not be broken.

Here is a quick example of some checkboxes and a jquery max limit.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(e) {
  if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 3) {
    $(this).prop('checked', false)
    alert("allowed only 3");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pricing-levels-3">
  <p><strong>(Select 3 Checkboxes)</strong></p>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">1<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">2<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">3<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">4<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">5<br>
</div>
```

Would I need to make an array that logs each chosen checkbox so when we go over our max, say over three into the fourth choice it unchecks the checkbox at the bottom of the array and then unloads it before loading the next one in?

In some other words, I sort of want this to work like a radio button but with the advantages of checkboxes where the user can check and uncheck multiple options but if they go over it just unloads one of their previous choices.

Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated. I have only been able to find examples of limiting the amount of checkboxes that can be selected. Nothing for this particular case.

Comment: I see nothing wrong in forcing the user to go consciously and deliberately uncheck a previous one - instead of automagically doing progammatic stuff behind the user's back. I would just make the remaining checkboxes `disabled` instead of alerting error messages. An input with `disabled` state is a well known UI/UX clue for the users.

Comment: Another way is to populate an array of three. When a fourth checkbox is selected you remove the oldest from the tail and insert the new as head. Kind of like the *Snake* game.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan would there be an issue if someone unchecked their second option. Then continues to make choices? Not sure if that would break the array stucture I guess.

Comment: Won't break anything (but let me think about it). You apply the snake-logic only when the array length is === 3 and new insertions are added. When the length is not 3, you insert/remove the usual way. You insert always to the array end, when you remove selections you remove them in their insertion index. Seems quite some large code to write though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's play around some examples before deciding on the pros/cons and ultimately what's best for a specific use case, UI/UX.
Just, **don't show alert popups** and stuff: the alerts are the interaction-flow disrupting factor, not the checkboxes alone.

Three different approaches ahead:

### 1. Disable checkboxes

The simplest and perhaps the best. The user has to consciously and deliberately uncheck a previous one - instead of our code automagically doing programmatic stuff behind the user's back. The `disabled` attribute is a well known UI/UX visual state.
Imagine you're ordering extras (sauces, spices, etc) and you can check three for the price. If the notice explicitly states that one can order up to three extras, logically one will uncheck a less desired product (to make place) for the more desired one. Such UI behavior can be picked up pretty quickly by the majority of users.

```js
const $checkboxes = $(".single-checkbox");
const max = 3;

$checkboxes.on("input", function() {
  const isMax = $checkboxes.filter(":checked").length === max;
  $checkboxes.not(":checked").prop("disabled", isMax);
});
```

```html
<div class="pricing-levels-3">
  <p><strong>(Select up to 3 products)</strong></p>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">1<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">2<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">3<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">4<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">5<br>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Pros:

- Simple code
- User action and choice is respected (no magic, programmatic unchecking is going on behind the user's back that might pass unnoticed, accessibility in mind)

Cons:

- None? Or none of importance. Correct me in comments if you think otherwise).

### 2. Uncheck last checked

Another way is to remember the **last checkbox**. When the `max` is reached - uncheck that last element. In this case the first two remain unchanged during that process

```js
const $checkboxes = $(".single-checkbox");
const max = 3;
let $last;

$checkboxes.on("input", function() {
  const isMax = $checkboxes.filter(":checked").length - 1 === max;
  if (isMax) $last.prop("checked", false);
  $last = $(this);
});
```

```html
<div class="pricing-levels-3">
  <p><strong>(Select up to 3 products)</strong></p>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">1<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">2<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">3<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">4<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">5<br>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Pros:

- Simple code
- Easier to cognitively understand that only the last checkbox is switching (only in the case the user can see all the checkboxes at once - which in never guaranteed on a scrollable app)

Cons:

- User selection is not respected
- Magic unchecking. Might pass unnoticed or seem like some UI bug
- The user might need to cognitively track the switching state and review visually once again all the choices states
- The unchecking logic can be picked up pretty quickly but to some might seem slightly random

### 3. *Snake* unchecking

FILO-Max. Like in a snake game, when `max` is reached, the oldest one is removed and the new one is appended to the Array.

```js
const $checkboxes = $(".single-checkbox");
const max = 3;
const checked = [];

$checkboxes.on("input", function() {
  const isMax = $checkboxes.filter(":checked").length - 1 === max;

  if (this.checked) {
    // Add to Array head on checked
    checked.push(this);
  } else {
    // Remove from array index on unchecked
    checked.splice(checked.indexOf(this), 1);
  }

  // Remove tail on maxxed
  if (isMax) {
    const $tail = $(checked.shift());
    $tail.prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="pricing-levels-3">
  <p><strong>(Select up to 3 products)</strong></p>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">1<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">2<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">3<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">4<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox">5<br>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Pros:

- Not sure...

Cons:

- Much more code
- Magic unchecking. Might pass unnoticed or seem like some UI bug
- The logic in which the checkboxes become programmatically unchecked/checked is not immediately obvious
- The cognitive logic in which a checkbox becomes unchecked becomes strange once the user starts to combine manual unchecking with the programmatic one

Comment: Thank you so much for your examples and also ux design ideas. I was pretty hung up on the idea that flow should be where the user also had the ability to keep checking boxes if they want but I can see how things happening behind the users back is a bad idea. There isn't a message that appears on my current site that is being developed so the user would often end up trying to click another box and have to second guess what was happening. 

I feel that the approach you suggested of disabling the checkboxes "greying them out" is going to be the best option. Thank you again.

Comment: @AuzurialPrints you're really welcome. One additional, really optional UX/UI suggestion would be: only once all three (max) products are checked - show below a notice saying something (positive, instead of of negative connotation) like "3 products selected! If you change mind about your selection, uncheck a selected product first." or something shorter. (This regards obviously for the first example with `disabled` checkboxes). Also a "Clear selection" button could also be an option. But again not sure any of those suggestions are needed. But it depends on the use-case.